# int object is not iterable on pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to make a script, every time when I click on my right mouse, the scrip sends the number that's stored in the x variable, and adds 1 to it.

My current script:

```
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

x = 1

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.right:
        if pressed:
            keyboard.type(x)
            x =+ 1
            return True

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
listener.join()
```

I find this code logical, but I keep getting an error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. I have tried to search for answer, but I haven't find a solution. Should I change it to str, but if so, how can I keep on adding numbers after every click?

```
Unhandled exception in listener callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 386, in _handler
    converted = self._convert(code, msg, lpdata)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 401, in _convert
    raise NotImplementedError() NotImplementedError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 211, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 390, in _handler
    self._handle(code, msg, lpdata)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse\_win32.py", line 212, in _handle
    self.on_click(data.pt.x, data.pt.y, button, pressed)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 127, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:   File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/klikkaus.py", line 11, in on_click
    keyboard.type(x)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 488, in type
    for i, character in enumerate(string): TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 386, in _handler
    converted = self._convert(code, msg, lpdata)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 401, in _convert
    raise NotImplementedError() NotImplementedError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/klikkaus.py", line 16, in <module>
    listener.join()   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 259, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 718, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 211, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 390, in _handler
    self._handle(code, msg, lpdata)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse\_win32.py", line 212, in _handle
    self.on_click(data.pt.x, data.pt.y, button, pressed)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 127, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:   File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/klikkaus.py", line 11, in on_click
    keyboard.type(x)   File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 488, in type
    for i, character in enumerate(string): TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The `x` in `on_click()` is a parameter, completely unrelated to the global variable `x`.  Even if it did refer to the global variable, `x =+ 1` just sets it to the same value it already had, you want `x += 1` to increment it.

Comment: What is the point of `keyboard.type(x)`? I suspect it works if you uncomment that line, maybe. Why do you need it? Plus what @jasonjarper said.

Comment: The point of the keyboard.type(x) is that it sends whatever is stored in the x variable (needs to be a number tho). It doesn't work, even if the ```keyboard.type(x)``` is not in the parameter.

Comment: So, change your function header to `def on_onclick(xx, yy, button, pressed):` and then make your New Year's resolution to choose better names for your globals so you don't run into conflicts like this.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that I couldn't use that variable. Anyways, even if I change the variable to ```num = 1```, I get the same errors. What I read from other places, you can't acutually set a number to a variable and send it using keyboard.type. Thanks tho for helping!